The Balmer spectrum and the thick tensor ideals of the derived category of a Hopf algebra
Given a Hopf algebra $H$ over a field $\mathbb{k}$, the category of finite-dimensional left-$H$-modules naturally becomes a rigid monoidal category with exact monoidal product. Thus clearly the monoidal product descends to the derived category $\mathcal{D}(H-\operatorname{mod})$ yielding a tensor triangulated category.
Can one classify the thick tensor ideals of $\mathcal{D}(H-\operatorname{mod})$ or the bounded subcategory $\mathcal{D}^{\operatorname{b}}(H-\operatorname{mod})$? Can one calculate (a non-commutative analogue) of the Balmer spectrum and is there a classification theorem?
I have tried to look at the literature, but I am not very familiar with tensor triangulated geometry and only found considerations of the stable module category $H-\underline{\operatorname{mod}}$, which to my knowledge differs from $\mathcal{D}^{\operatorname{b}}(H-\operatorname{mod})$ by the perfect complexes in the sense of the Verdier quotient $\mathcal{D}^{\operatorname{b}}(H-\operatorname{mod}) / \mathcal{D}^{\operatorname{perf}}(H-\operatorname{mod}) \cong H-\underline{\operatorname{mod}}$.

If the Hopf algebra is finite dimensional and cocommutative, then yes, in terms of the spectrum of the cohomology ring. The key phrase is "finite group scheme". Otherwise, not much is known. Not even finite generation of cohomology.
